Covariance inversion for Gaussian process
Background
Let $x=f(u_x)\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $y=[f(u_y^1)\cdots f(u_y^{N})]\in\mathbb{R}^N$ for some function $f:u \in \mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$.
Given $y$, $u_x$, $u_{y}^1,\dots, u_{y}^{N}$, I need to compute the following vector
\begin{equation*}
x = \Sigma_{xy}\,\Sigma_{y}^{-1} y
\end{equation*}
and the following matrix
\begin{equation*}
P=\Sigma_x-\Sigma_{xy}\Sigma_y^{-1}\Sigma_{xy}'
\end{equation*}
The cross-covariance $\Sigma_{xy}$ and covariance $\Sigma_y$ come from the wrapped kernel
\begin{equation*}
k(u_1,u_2)\triangleq \sigma_1^2 \exp\left[-\frac{2 \sin^2 \left(\frac{|u_1-u_2|}{2}\right)}{\ell^2}\right]+\sigma_2^2
\end{equation*}
where $\sigma_1, \ell, \sigma_2$ are given hyperparameters.
Accordingly, the cross-covariance $\Sigma_{xy}\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times N}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma_{xy}\triangleq\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
k(u_x,u_y^1) & \cdots & k(u_x, u_y^N)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
and the covariance $\Sigma_y \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma_{y}\triangleq\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
k(u_y^{1},u_y^1) & \cdots & k(u_y^{1}, u_y^N) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k(u_y^N, u_y^1) & \cdots & k(u_y^{N}, u_y^N) \\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
Problem
For simplicity, consider the case where
\begin{equation*}
u_y^j \triangleq \frac{2 \pi }{N-1} (j-1) \qquad j = 1,\dots,N
\end{equation*}
To fix the ideas, consider $\sigma_1 \triangleq \sigma_2 \triangleq 2, \ell\triangleq \pi/4,$. Numerically, it turns out that when $N$ is sufficiently big, say $N\triangleq 50$, $\Sigma$ become ill-conditioned. In particular, some eigenvalue become negative (however, with absolute value particularly small), while some other positive eigenvalue become large.
Clearly, this fact does not sound particularly good since I have to compute $x$ and $P$ - two operations that involve the inversion of $\Sigma_y$.
So far, my trivial solution to mitigate this bad situation is to re-inforce the diagonal of  $\Sigma_y$ by "artificially" introducing a term $\epsilon I_N$, i.e. I compute $x$ and $P$ with the "wrong" equations
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x &= \Sigma_{xy} (\Sigma_y+\epsilon I_N)^{-1} y \\
P &= \Sigma_{x} -  \Sigma_{xy} (\Sigma_y+\epsilon I_N)^{-1} \Sigma_{xy}'
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
here $I_N$ is the $N\times N$ identity matrix while $\epsilon$ is a small positive scalar (e.g. $10^{-7}$).
Questions
I understand that my problem is not so uncommon in Gaussian process estimation. For what I've seen, a suggested solution is to avoid the inversion of $\Sigma_y$ but rather exploit its Cholesky decomposition. The problem is that I'm not able to decompose $\Sigma_y$ because some eigenvalue is not strictly positive. Thus, currently I'm not able to employ this solution. I have two questions:

How to compute $x$ and $P$ without introducing any "artificial distortion" on $\Sigma_y$?
Provided that $f(\cdot)$ is periodic with period $\pi$, is it possible to modify the kernel so that there is no problem at all with the conditioning of $\Sigma_y$?


If an eigenvalue is not "strictly positive" then using $LDL^T$ is a good option to explore. In the case of positive semi-definite we won't be able to ensure uniqueness of $D$ but other than we are good to go. Of course if there are negative eigenvalues, then we don't have a valid covariance matrix anyway so no need to worry about the decomposition, we need to make our fix "further up".
